# Can't acces part of my web JQuery Mobile and tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm having a little trouble and i don't know how to solve it. The problem is that i have a HTML5 code with diferents pages (tags with ids), i'm using Jquery Mobile to swith between the pages with buttons. I don't know why, but one of the button stop working (Option button), but the others keep working just fine as always. This is the html code:

**UPDATED CODE!**

```
</head>
<body>

<!-- ****************    PAG  PRINCIPAL    **************** -->

<div data-role="page" id="principal">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3 id="nombreAplicacion">
            Nombre Aplicacion
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; position: relative; background-color: #fbfbfb; border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;"
        id="imagenUsuario">
            <img id="imagenUsuario" src="http://codiqa.com/static/images/v2/image.png"
            alt="image" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -18px">
        </div>
        <h4 id="nombreUsuario">  
            <p id="nmb">Nombre Usuario </p>               
        </h4>
        <a id="botonEjercicios" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slideup"
        data-theme="a" href="#ejercicios" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">
            Ejercicios
        </a>
        <a id="botonEstadisticas" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse"
        data-transition="slidedown" data-theme="a" href="#estadisticas" data-icon="arrow-d"
        data-iconpos="left">
            Estadisticas
        </a>
        <a data-role="button" data-transition="flow" data-theme="a" href="#opciones"
        data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="left">
            Opciones
        </a>
        <a data-role="button" data-transition="flow" data-theme="a" id="botonReset"
        data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="left">
            Reset Datos Ejercicios
        </a>
    </div>
</div>




<!-- ****************      EJERCICIOS      **************** -->
<div data-role="page" id="ejercicios">

</div>

<!-- ****************  ACTIVAR  EJERCICIOS  *************** -->
<div data-role="page" id="activarEjercicios">

</div>

<!-- ****************    ESTADISTICAS      **************** -->
<div data-role="page" id="estadisticas">

</div>

<!-- ****************      OPCIONES      **************** -->
<div data-role="page" id="opciones">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine if i try it in Google Chrome offline (just reading the html), but with firefox the option butoon does not work. In my online page, doesn't work with chrome or firefox neither

Comment: What do you mean by not working? The button doesn't take you to the page? Is the page in the same file of the homepage?

Comment: The page is in the same file, i got differents "<div>" and they works as individual pages. When i press a button, that div shows up with some animation (like: flow or slideup). Whats happend is that when i try the "Option Button" doesn't take me to the option div (option page), something like the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with a function, i fixed the code and now it works. The strange thing is that in Google Chrome works with the broken code, don't know why is that...